# bash: repeatedly executed script in .bash_profile blocks login

Tags: bash, login, .bash-profile

I have a bash script (let's call it script.sh) which looks like this

```
while true; do
  if [ $someFile -eq = "1" ]
  then
    # make laptop LED blink here
  fi
done
```

So when some file has some value (in my case, this file is changed when messages arrives), the script make a LED blink. As you can guess, this script never stops.

I usually call it when I need to know wether there is new mail and I can't open the laptop and check the screen.

Today I said to myself: let's put this in .bash_profile so the script gets fired up at login.

But when I try to login, alas the screen freezes.

How can I tell bash: execute this, but in a non blocking way?

Or: is there another solution to fire this at startup without freezing the machine?

Answer (score 3):

Nice thought. But, you have stalled the login sequence in your infinite loop `:-)`
So, try to launch your script with a command like,

```
nohup ~/script.sh &
```

That way, it will be sent into background and let your login continue.

Better still, read up about `cron` and `sleep` ...

Comment: mhhh, I can login with `nohup ~/script.sh &`, but it seems the script is not working...

Comment: Why `nohup`? Sending it to the background should be enough shouldn't it?

Comment: @terdon, just a habit `:)` you are right, send it to background is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be to add this to `cron`. Create a crontab with the following line:

```
@reboot ~/script.sh &
```

There may also be complications from the way you are making the led blink. You might get better answers if you include the entire script so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than running this via cron with an explicit loop, read up on [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), "a Linux kernel subsystem that acts to extend filesystems to notice changes to the filesystem, and report those changes to applications".

The [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) tools documentation show how to install and give usage examples.